# CodeIgniter Active Record - Remove all but last 10 that match criteria

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to remove all results but the last 10 from a table. That shouldn't be too hard, but they also have to match a certain criteria.

The table looks like this;

```
chat_id
location_id
user_id
message
created
```

Technically it has to remove everything with a specific location_id, and keep the last 10 records in the table.

Is this possible with the Active Record class?

THanks in advance

Comment: It's probably easier to just use plain SQL to do this task.

Comment: are u trying to first say filter out all records with location_id = 'value' and then from that list , delete all except last 10  records ? could u be more precise about "last 10" im assuming your records are arranged by chat_id and ur trying to get the last 10 chat_id @RoelLarik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all an optimal solution, but I guess this might help.

I'm assuming from your question that the criteria is a particular `location_id`.

If the created field is a timestamp field and by last 10 records, you mean the 10 most recent records, you can use a query similar to this:

```
DELETE FROM `table` 
WHERE created<
    (select min(a.cdate) from 
        (
         select b.created as cdate from `table` b
         where b.location_id=<<loc_id>>
         order by b.created desc limit 10
        ) a
    )
AND location_id=<<loc_id>>;
```

Answer (score 0):

ill come up with active records in a while you can try this sql query :

```
$this->db->query('
delete from table_name where chat_id NOT IN 
(select chat_id from table_name where location_id=1292 order by chat_id DESC LIMIT 10)
')
```